# SQL Server table creation error : There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

A very basic script is driving me crazy. It says it cant find a referenced key. Not idea what it's all about. I'm am using SQL SERVER 2014 and this script is for the creation of my database tables. I'm trying to make the `id_TABLE_1` in the table `TABLE_2` reference the id of the table `TABLE_1`.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1
(
    id int identity,
    email varchar(50) not null,

    constraint PK_TABLE_1 primary key (id,email)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2
(
    id int identity,
    id_TABLE_1 int not null,
         
    constraint PK_TABLE_2 primary key (id),
    constraint FK_TABLE_2 foreign key (id_TABLE_1) 
        references TABLE_1(id) on delete cascade
)
GO
```

The error is :

> **Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 32**
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'TABLE_1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_TABLE_2'.
>
> **Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 32**
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Can you help me here ?

Comment: The error message explains exactly what's wrong. There's no index on just the `OBJET_GEO.id` column.

Comment: Nope, your primary key is a composite key containing `id,email_utilisateur` columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comment, you are trying to reference an index that doesn't exist. The primary key on your `TABLE_1` table is a composite key containing two columns: `id` and `email`.

For this to compile, you can either alter your primary key to:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE_1 PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

or create a new index on just the `id` column:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TABLE_1_id ON TABLE_1 (id);
```

Comment: omg I did not even see that. Ok What I'll do is keep `id` as primary key and use UNIQUE (id,email) as combination

Comment: Think about what adding a unique index on `id` and `email` will achieve. If you want a unique email address per row then only include `email` in your unique index.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense to have a composite primary key that includes an identity column.  The id column is already unique and non-NULL, so it should be the primary key.

If you want the email to be unique as well then remove it from the primary key and declare it as unique.

Comment: Not related to my issue.  Thanks for your advice though.

Comment: I often see composite clustering keys that consist of two columns, the second being an identity. For example, `(OrderKey, OrderLineKey)` will ensure that all lines for the same order are together. And since they'll usually be created at the same time, index fragmentation isn't an issue. (That said, I've never seen one where the identity column is first.)

Comment: @JonathanAllen As a rookie, I don't quite see the difference in the order of fields in a UNIQUE or PK constraint.

Comment: The constraint is also an index. So it is the difference between sorting by first name, last name or by last name, first name.

Comment: @JonathanAllen Cool I unserstand it. Unique and PK will check in the order of the fields supplied. So no need to check the identity first as it is always different from row to row right ?

Comment: @JonathanAllen . . . The context is "as the first key", which is what the OP was doing.